# Filter records in AppleScript

Tags: applescript, record

Trying to grab certain records based on property value:

```
set x to {{a:1, b:2, c:"yes"}, {a:2, b:2, c:""}, {a:3, b:2, c:"no"}}
get every item of x whose (c ≠ "")
```

gives

```
error "The variable c is not defined." number -2753 from "c"
```

What am I doing wrong?

This loop works:

```
set y to {}
repeat with i in x
    if i's c ≠ "" then
        set end of y to i
    end if
end repeat
get y
```

... gives:

`{item 1 of {{a:1, b:2, c:"yes"}, {a:2, b:2, c:""}, {a:3, b:2, c:"no"}},
 item 3 of {{a:1, b:2, c:"yes"}, {a:2, b:2, c:""}, {a:3, b:2, c:"no"}}}`

... but seems like overkill, and seems like it's pointers to the original record?

Answer (score 1):

AppleScript records aren't able to be filtered in the manner you hoped they would be, so with plain AppleScript, you're exactly right in both your approach using the repeat loop, and in the observation that it's returning references to the values rather than the values themselves.

To dereference these, change your final line to

```
get y's contents
```

or

```
get the contents of y
```

If you don't mind injecting a bit of Objective-C into your script, we can create a *script object* that defines the implementation of a `filterItems` handler you can use to filter lists through a *predicate string*, which actually gives you a lot more power over how things and what things gets filtered:

```
script array
    use framework "Foundation"

    property this : a reference to current application
    property NSArray : a reference to NSArray of this
    property NSPredicate : a reference to NSPredicate of this


    to filterItems for x as string given list:L
        local L, x

        NSPredicate's predicateWithFormat:x
        (NSArray's arrayWithArray:L)'s ¬
            filteredArrayUsingPredicate:result
        result as anything
    end filterItems
end script
```

You can pop this at the bottom of your script to keep it out of the way, then use it to filter your list of records like so:

```
set x to {{a:1, b:2, c:"yes"}, {a:2, b:2, c:""}, {a:3, b:2, c:"no"}}

filterItems of array for "c!=''" given list:x
    --> {{a:1, b:2, c:"yes"}, {a:3, b:2, c:"no"}}
```

Note, however, that there are differences in the ways Objective-C and AppleScript perform comparisons.  For instance, if we declare x as:

```
set x to {{a:1, b:2}, {a:2, b:2, c:""}, {a:3, b:2, c:"no"}}
```

any hypothetical AppleScript filter instructed to predicate on `c` not being an empty string would throw an error as soon as it came across an object (item 1 of x: `{a:1, b:2}`) that didn't contain the property `c`.  Objective-C is a little more inclusive in its evaluation:

```
filterItems of array for "c!=''" given list:x
    --> {{a:1, b:2}, {a:3, b:2, c:"no"}}
```

If you were surprised by the inclusion of `{a:1, b:2}` in this result, you'll be wanting to predicate the filter around two conditions, namely that the objects returned contain a property called `c`, and that this property is not an empty string:

```
filterItems of array for "SELF CONTAINS c && c!=''" given list:x
    --> {a:3, b:2, c:"no"}
```

Notice here that, because the result is a single object, unlike AppleScript, Objective-C will dispense with the formality of returning a single-item `list`, and return the object itself, which is a `record`.

For more information about predicate strings and how to formulate them, see the section [*At A Glance*](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/AdditionalChapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001798-SW1) for a quick rundown of general syntax, and everything from [*Basic Comparisons*](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-215832) down to the end of that page for the different operators that can be used on the different types of values.

However, if you need a bit of extra help forming the predicate string to cater for specific cases, leave a comment and I'll try to help you out.